# Ошибка вставки элемента в multimap

Tags: stl, qt, c++

Есть следующий код:

```
std::vector<xml::Face>::const_iterator iter = faces.begin();

while (iter != faces.end()) {

    iter->getSex();

    if(iter->getSex() == "male") {

        //fileMapMale_.insert(std::multimap<xml::Face, QFileInfo>::value_type(*iter,fileImageName));

    } else if(iter->getSex() == "female") {

        //fileMapFemale_.insert(std::multimap<xml::Face, QFileInfo>::value_type(*iter,fileImageName));

    } else  if(iter->getSex() == "unknow") {

        //fileMapUnknow_.insert(std::multimap<xml::Face, QFileInfo>::value_type(*iter,fileImageName));

    }

    ++iter;

}
```

Если строки расскоментировать, то компилятор выдает ошибку:  `no match for 'operator<' in '__x < __y'`

Как исправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компилятор говорит вам о том, что для вашего класса не задан ***оператор сравнения '<'***, соответственно, шаблонная функция не знает, как ей сравнить два элемента, которые вы ей передаете.

Попробуйте для ваших классов определить **оператор сравнения '<'**, и, скорее всего, ваша проблема решится.

Internally, multimap containers keep all their elements sorted following the criterion specified by its comparison object on construction. Each element is inserted in its respective position following this ordering.
- как раз объясняет почему это происходит. insert пытается вставить элемент в карту, на позицию, сравнивая с остальными элементами, но сделать этого не может, т.к. отсутствует оператор сравнения. Для поиска, кстати, скорее всего используется двоичный поиск. Вот Вам и причина.

Comment: да, спасибо, так и есть.